# LINUX GNU Create New user Postgres DB in Makefile

Tags: linux, postgresql, unix, makefile

I'm new with Makefile. I need to automate create user for postgres terminal.

I tried this example and it did not work for me:

```
createuser:
    @echo "$(OK_COLOR)==> create user$(NO_COLOR)"
    @psql mydbdevelopmentname
    @create user myusername;
    @/q
    @echo "$(OK_COLOR)==> Done$(NO_COLOR)"
```

Neither `@create user myusername;` nor `@/q` works.

When I ran `make createuser` and exit manually with \q from postgres terminal, I receive this error:

```
/bin/sh: create: command not found
make: *** [createuser] Error 127
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When debugging makefiles, the `@` modifier is unhelpful, as it no longer shows those commands before executing them.

I suspect that you actually wanted to pass `create user myusername` to your `psql` line, but you wrote it as a separate command.  You need to make sure that `psql` sees it:

```
psql -c "create user myusername" mydbdevelopmentname
```

Don't forget to declare your target as a dependency of `.PHONY`.

I'll note in passing that Make is generally a poor choice to use as a scripting language - it's much better for making targets from their dependencies, as it's designed for.  This kind of thing is more suited to a language such as Bash or Python.

Comment: I'm getting different error now  `psql: FATAL:  role "create user myusername" does not exist
make: *** [createuser] Error 2`

Comment: Mixed it up with MySQL - I meant `-c`, not `-e` (as the man page would have shown you if you'd bothered).